# Codeigniter REST API elapsed time

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, time, response

I'm using codeigniter REST-API (Author: philsturgeon Ref URL:

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver)

I want to add to the response how much time it took the service to generate and process the response.

I am trying to use `$this->benchmark->elapsed_time()` in my controller, but it doesn't send the time instead it sends

```
"success": 1,"took": "{elapsed_time}",
```

I tried to edit the the main controller of the api `abstract class REST_Controller extends CI_Controller` and append the elapsed time to the final output send by `public function response($data = null, $http_code = null, $continue = false)`

But no luck, i keep receiving `"{elapsed_time}"` 
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your `elapsed_time` by using this

```
$this->benchmark->mark('code_start');

// Some code happens here

$this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end');
```

Comment: This one will work, but i want the entire time. from the moment the request initialised until the response is sent.

Comment: It sound good it work.Write your whole code between `mark('code_start');` and mark('code_end'); and last you get `elapsed_time` for your code

Comment: also write your initialized code inside `code_start`

Comment: yeah i just did that, i added `mark('code_start');` to the construct function of REST_Controller. Thank You, i think i should have tried before i ask the question, now i feel silly :s